# Audacious run when I press Open with or Show in Folder in XFCE in Arch for any kind of file

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, bugs

It's funny but audacious runs when I don't even request for it. For example, when I press Open Folder in Chrome downloads or when I choose Browse Packages in Sublime Text. A file for Open Folder in Chrome may not be a music file.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Audacious registers itself as an application that can handle directory MIME type (more precisely `inode/directory`).  This can be seen in its .desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/audacious.desktop` (location might be different on Arch) where `MimeType` variable is set.

On your system for `inode/directory` MIME type, either:

- there is no other application that can handle it, only Audacious
- there are more such applications but Audacious is set as default for it
- there are more such applications but none of them is set as default for it (and Audacious is simply the first)

To work with MIME associations use `xdg-mime` command.  For example, to set Firefox to open directories (you may choose your preferred file manager instead of Firefox) execute:

```
xdg-mime default firefox.desktop inode/directory
```

Then you can check the result with:

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory                                        
firefox.desktop
```

And you can test if it is working with `xdg-open`:

```
xdg-open /tmp
```

Now Firefox should be launched showing the content of `/tmp`.

`xdg-mime` writes its settings to `~/.local/share/applications/` or -- if you use `--mode system` option -- it writes to `/etc/xdg/applications/` (you have to be root in this case).

It is likely that your desktop environment also provides a way to change associations.

Answer (score 1):

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=671807#p671807

He said:

> in XFCE, I use Thunar.basically edit
>   `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`  and add to the end (with
>   a blank line afterwards)
>
> ```
> [Default Applications]
> x-directory/normal=Thunar.desktop
> ```
>
> To open with Dolphin:
>
> ```
> [Default Applications]
> x-directory/normal=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
> ```

I'm using Debian9, It works for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide an answer to the problem with `Audacious`. It may avoid it but it isn't really a solution to the problem.

Comment: @bu5hman Audacious has set itself to open directories. Doing this you set which application to open them. I've set thunar.desktop and does work (manjaro, xfce4), no more audacious is opened when trying to invoke some directory from xdg. Try things before blame...